# How can I get computer generated content approved/edited by humans that qualify?

Tags: php, cms, crowdsourcing, voting, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a verb conjugator. The algorithm works, but sometimes their are irregular verbs.

I know some programming, so I am willing to modify something to fit my needs. I don't care what programming language, although I prefer php or ruby.

I am look for a framework or CMS solution or Wordpress plugin that will let me do some or all of the following:

1) Allow the community to downvote certain charts if they aren't real verbs or there is some other error.

2) Give more weight to users who have shown they make reliable edits.

3) Gray out content that has been deemed incorrect by the community.

4) Allow a single or few words to be corrected instead of downvoting the whole chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I decided to go a different direction, I did find [crowdflower.com](http://crowdflower.com) to be a good solution to the problem posed in the question above.